# How to hide selected/checked item's divider in LinearLayout and ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-linearlayout, divider, android-selector

### Background

I have some ListViews and LinearLayouts, each has dividers between items.

### The problem

When selecting/checking an item, I would like to know how to have its dividers (above and below it) to become hidden (invisible, but still take space)

The reason for this is that the items have a selected-background (using a selector) which, together with the dividers, look pretty bad.

In short I want to avoid this scenario:

- item
- divider
- item
- divider
- **selected-item**
- divider
- item
- divider
- item

Instead, I wish to have this:

- item
- divider
- item
- **selected-item**
- item
- divider
- item

This looks even worse in case I use android:dividerPadding , which shows something like that:

- empty-space, divider, and again empty-space
- **selected-item**
- empty-space, divider, and again empty-space

The problem is that I can't find out how to do such a thing

I've noticed that Google handled this issue on the Play store's app, inside the navigation drawer: They removed the dividers, and set the selected items to simply be bold.
On most cases though, this isn't handled

### The question

Is there a way to do it, other than putting the dividers in the views and updating their visibility according to which item is being selected/checked ?

Is there maybe a workaround of making the selector take a bit more space than it really needs, so that when the item is selected, it will be on top of the dividers?